# MySQL - Selecting only the default value from column

Tags: java, mysql, select, default

I am wondering is it possible to select only the default value of empty column?
I have absolutely empty table and I want just to select one of the columns default value - it is important for my JAVA app which is filling the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the default from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

```
select COLUMN_DEFAULT
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA='your_db' and TABLE_NAME='your_table' and COLUMN_NAME='your_column'
```

Comment: Ah, I tend to forget about `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for some reason, that's the third (or perhaps first) way. :-)

Comment: Codd's 4th rule ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of two ways:

#### Inserting a row

1. Insert a row without specifying a value for that column
2. Select the column from that row; it will have the default value of the column
3. Delete the row

...probably all in a transaction so nothing else sees it.

#### Using `describe` (`explain`)

The `describe` command (aka [`explain`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)) describes objects in the system, including tables. So if you do `explain YourTable`, you'll get back information about the table, including its default values.

Here's an example from that linked documentation:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE City;
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−+−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−+−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| Id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name       | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Country    | char(3)  | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| District   | char(20) | YES  | MUL |         |                |
| Population | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−+−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

So you can extract the default from the `Default` column in the returned rows.

---

Ah, of course, there's a third way, see [slaakso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55275370/157247) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a default value for a column when you create a table, if you just want MySQL to insert it automatically:

```
create table my_table (i INT DEFAULT 1);
```

But if you mean you want the default value which is stored in the DB dictionary, you can get it by this query:

```
SELECT Column_Default
  FROM Information_Schema.Columns
WHERE Table_Schema = 'yourSchema'
  AND Table_Name = 'yourTableName'
  AND Column_Name = 'yourColumnName'
```